# Hash to convert month to number

Tags: perl

I am using hash to convert month into number.

```
%mon2num = qw(
    jan 1  feb 2  mar 3  apr 4  may 5  jun 6
    jul 7  aug 8  sep 9  oct 10 nov 11 dec 12
);
```

Here i want to make all month jan, feb..dec case insensitive.Let me know how to do.

Answer (score 6):

Use `lc`:

```
for my $month (qw(Jan FEB mar)) {
    print "$month --> ", $mon2num{lc $month}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Actually , Month could be Either Jan, jan, JAN so i want it case insensitive.